# How do I access an image stored in File System (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to access a user uploaded image, which is stored under `wwwroot/images/alunos` directly in the view

```
<div class="panel-body col-lg-6">
    <h4>Fotografia do aluno</h4>
    <img src="@Model.Image_Name" width="500" height="300" alt="Fotografia do aluno"/>
</div>
```

`@Model.Image_Name` has the value:

```
"C:\\Users\\David\\Desktop\\EsjaGrades\\EsjaGrades\\wwwroot\\images\\alunos\\img.jpg"
```

Which is the correct path of the image but I am given the error **"Not allowed to load local resource: path"** in the browser.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Please reproduce the actual value of `@Model.Image_Name` in your question.

Comment: Right; it's looking for that image path in the *client's* machine, not the server's. You need to convert that path to one based on the URL, not the file system (likely "/images/alunos/img.jpg").

Answer (score 3):

Was trying to access the image in the client's machine. Started using relative path and it worked!